# FBConnect logout button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fbconnect

I am using the FBConnect lib to allow users to post data to their facebook pages. I was successfully able to  establish a session and allow a user to post to their wall.

My question is this: 
There is a facebook 'logout' button that is suspended in the top left corner of my view after I've logged into facebook. How do I disable or move this button? I did not find any documentation in the api that this button would appear.

Need some advice on how to manage this mysterious button.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

In the FBConnect folder in your xcode project, you should have a FBDialog.m with a initWithSession:(FBSession*)session in there you should find everything about the facebook login and logout buttons including the .png images that they point to.

Hope this helps.